# Grammar Rule for Every

Tags: grammar

Could you please help me with the question below?

Which one is correct and why?

> Every man and woman voted for __________ leaders.
> A. their
> B. his
> C. her
> D. theirs

My answer is "A" but the book answers "B".

Comment: How old is the book?

Comment: It was published in 2007.

Comment: Please give **full** details of the book: name, editor, publisher, first publication date and reprint date. English has changed over time, and in this particular regard quite a lot recently. The language also differs around the world, so all of this information is helpful.

Comment: 'Every man and boy took his phone' but ''Every man and woman took their phone'. A singular-form possessive pronoun is required; this may need to be _singular 'their'_.

Comment: Since women are specifically mentioned, _his_ is obviously wrong even without allowing for modern gender politics.